# Flutter app stopped working on emulator/simulator (Windows 10 and MacOS)

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, ios-simulator, daemon

My flutter project runs on real devices with F5 or with

> flutter run --release

on real devices connected to the PC. It also worked on emulators (Windows 10) and simulators (macOS) but it stopped, getting an endless loading screen right after splash screen. On iOS i got this message in the logs:

> PET daemon has launched

> Failed to initialize PET service. Exiting...

> Failed to initialize the tracker

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was the internet connection. Tried another one and it works.